# How to use ipad directory structure as source for website images?

Tags: php, html, ios, ipad, directory

I have a website developed in PHP and mysql.The website has a module for staff member to access from their tablet pcs and ipad.

To optimize performance,I am loading product images of LIVE website module from local tablet pcs's drives .For example,in my html image tag my image source looks like this:

```
  <img class="main-product-image"src="file:///C:\Staff\images\uploads\<?=str_replace('/','\\',$img);?>" width="400" height="300" alt="<?=$product->Name?>" />
```

How can achieve the same behaviour on Ipad?

I am not familiar with Ipad directory structure.

Is there anyway i could hardcode directory strcuture like mentioned above??What strategy i will need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on iPad. On iOS you don't have access to file system. Only way is to create application with Web View (iOS framework) and save data in local files of this App.